# S-Off Evo 4G LTE

Tags: htc, s-off

So I have an HTC Evo 4G LTE that I'm working on, and I upgraded Hboot to version 2.10. That probably wasn't quite as brilliant of an idea as I thought, being as now I can't seem to gain S-Off. I know how to get S-Off on Hboot version 2.09, but when I ran the RUU which included that, it gave me the error "ERROR [140]: BOOTLOADER VERSION ERROR," so I figure it doesn't want to *downgrade* anything. Can I get back to Hboot 2.09, or gain S-Off some other way?

Comment: Here's my research, although it hasn't helped me as of yet.

http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-lte-rooting-rom-s-hacks/254028-guide-how-return-stock-phone-you-think-you-bricked.html

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964371

http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-3d-rooting-roms-hacks/266778-help-unable-flash-ruu.html

Comment: Can't you use ADB to install Hboot 2.09

Answer (score 0):

With S-On but the bootloader unlocked, I believe you can flash an official stock Firmware (and downgrade)
Then Soff again.

After getting S-OFf, ungrade Hboot only with a hacked version.
Then flash roms via TWRP only.

Comment: Alright, but when I go through the HTCDev method again, it still says 'relocked.'